# Partial update doesn't work with master pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, master-pages

I am working on a C# asp.net web forms project. It has two master pages. I 
have an user control which reads data from database, 
creates an un-ordered list in html string and populates a placeholder with 
it. This user control has to be automatically 
refreshed every 2 minutes. I have included this usercontrol on the parent 
master page. I have the following code to refresh the 
user control, which I have obtained through another stackoverflow answer. 
The problem is that the entire master page refreshes, and I am not sure why.

Is there a way to make that only the user control which has the UpdatePanel 
    refreshes?

Outer Master Page:

```
  <body>
  <form id="frmMain" role="form" method="post" runat="server">
    <div>
       <uc2:PendingOrders runat="server" ID="PendingOrders" />
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainBodyContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
 </body>
```

User Control:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server" 
 EnablePartialRendering="True"></asp:ScriptManager> 
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode = "Conditional" 
  runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="20000" 
  OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="lblMyOrders"></asp:PlaceHolder>

  </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

User Control Code behind:

```
   protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //This method creates the html string with data as an unordered list 
      and
      //populates asp:PlaceHolder inte updatepanel
      GetData();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel1's Content will be update by Timer1_Tick.

"entire master page refreshes" means master page's Page_Load will be call while Timer1 been trigger? 
UpdatePanel always post entire page back server and only render UpdatePanel1's Content.

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening. First it goes to the master page's page_load event and then to the Timer1_Tick. Because of this the page flickers. I want to avoid it.

Comment: only UpdatePanel1 will flicker *** [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: The entire page reloads and flickers!

Comment: i use your code work well  `<asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server"
    EnablePartialRendering="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional"
    runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"
            OnTick="Timer1_OnTick">
        </asp:Timer>

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="lblMyOrders"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
   
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: timer1 inside the UpdatePanel1 , the trigger doesn't need to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in our project the EnablePartialRendering was set to false on the Master Page, if set to true the whole project breaks.
To fix the problem, I defined another master page without ScriptManager and added the ScriptManager to the page in which I wanted to use UpdatePanels with the EnablePartialRendering attribute set to True.
This fixed the problem.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
```